# Getting an input element's value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, textinput, html-input

How can I get the value of an input element in jQuery?

Comment: Felix: "google it" is not [an acceptable answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).

Comment: Mark i think Felix is not giving an answer just extending help to find solution by himself

Comment: on the other hand - good to have an answer to everything on SO :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is your `textbox`:

```
<input type="text" id="mytextBox" value="" />
```

You will be getting it's `value` using the textbox's `ID=mytextBox`...

```
var value = $("#mytextBox").val()
```

### References

- [JQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#elementId").val()
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the `val()` function, as in:

```
$('#someInput').val();
```

You can also use the attr function to find the value for some fields

```
$('#someInput').attr('value');
```

Comment: how to set the attribute ?

Answer (score 3):

The `val` function gets or sets the value of an input field.

Set the input value to "Hello world":

```
$('#myInput').val('Hello world');
```

Get the input value:

```
$('#myInput').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery('inputElement').val() to get the values of input(form) elements